# Passing an array of bytes to another class ORMlite

Tags: java, android, constructor, ormlite

I am developing a small recipe management tool for android. For data storage I am using the ORMLite Library. Now I'm trying to save an image as a byte array to the database. Somehow this is not working and i can't figure out why.

This is the constructor of the class, that the byte array is passed to

```
public class RecipeTable {
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
int id;
@DatabaseField
String cocktailName;
@DatabaseField
int addition1;
@DatabaseField
int addition2;
@DatabaseField
int addition3;
@DatabaseField
int addition4;
@DatabaseField
int addition5;
@DatabaseField
int addition6;
@DatabaseField (dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY, columnName = "yo")
byte[] imageBytes;
@DatabaseField
Date date;

public RecipeTable(){
}

public RecipeTable(String cocktailName, int addition1, int addition2, int addition3, int addition4, int addition5, int addition6, byte[] imageBytesa) {
    super();
    this.cocktailName = cocktailName;
    this.addition1 = addition1;
    this.addition2 = addition2;
    this.addition3 = addition3;
    this.addition4 = addition4;
    this.addition5 = addition5;
    this.addition6 = addition6;
    this.imageBytes = imageBytesa;

    this.date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("id", id);
        jsonObject.put("cocktailName", cocktailName);
        jsonObject.put("addition1", addition1);
        jsonObject.put("addition2", addition2);
        jsonObject.put("addition3", addition3);
        jsonObject.put("addition4", addition4);
        jsonObject.put("addition5", addition5);
        jsonObject.put("addition6", addition6);
        jsonObject.put("imageByte", imageBytes);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
public  byte[] getImageBytes(){return imageBytes;}
public int getId(){return id;}
public String getAddition1(){return "yihha";}
```

}

in another class I'm creating an object of RecipeTable

```
 recipeDao.create(new RecipeTable(etCocktailName.getText().toString(), additionAmounts[0],additionAmounts[1],additionAmounts[2],additionAmounts[3],
                                         additionAmounts[4],additionAmounts[5],imageByte));
```

the imageByte is created like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);
                        imageByte = stream.toByteArray();
```

when I'm trying to get the imageByte value of the created object, it has the value null. (recipeTable.get(0).getImageBytes())
this is what my output is showing (Log.d):

D/imageByte: [-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72...

D/Content of Recipe:: [{"id":1,"cocktailName":"x","addition1":1,"addition2":1,"addition3":1,"addition4":1,"addition5":11,"addition6":1}]

The imageByte is missing. I think it was not passed correctly

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Dimon you should spend some time researching about telescoping constructors and factory implementations

Comment: how about pass it as an array instead of passing each element of it as a seperate parameter?

Comment: thank you for your responses. @OnurA. what do you mean exactly? I thought the imageView is an array of bytes?

Comment: I meant, instead of defining the constructor as public RecipeTable(String cocktailName, int addition1, ... int addition6, byte[] imageBytesa), you can define it as public RecipeTable(String cocktailName, int[] additions, byte[] imageBytesa). OR if you think you don't know the exact size of it? No problem you can define it as a variable-length argument like so, public RecipeTable(String cocktailName, byte[] imageBytesa, int... additions). But beware that variable-length arguments should be placed at the end of the parameter list definition.

Comment: okay, thank you. I'm going to change it. But more importantly. Do you have any idea why the array is not passed? ^^

Comment: i've now initialized the imageByte array in the recipeTable class like this:
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[488584]; (this is the number of bytes for a specific picture). but still the result of the output is: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...]

Comment: @Dimon probably it propduces it null when you're creating it, or maybe theere is an issue with injection with Database.

Comment: you're right. there must be some issue with the database injection. I tried it in another class and it works perfectly fine